# Python file to execute commands in docker

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker

i want to cd to a certain directory in **docker** when a button is clicked , so i need a python command to do that , i tried

```
os.system("sudo docker start jolly_allen ;sudo docker exec -i -t    jolly_allen /bin/bash ; sudo docker exec -i -t jolly_allen -c cd    /   tensorflow")
```

and

`os.system("sudo docker run jolly_allen /bin/bash -c cd /tensorflow")`

But nothing worked.

Thank you !

Comment: Try without `sudo`? It might help to add the error log to your question.

Comment: Can you add more details? What do you mean "Nothing worked", any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Explore the Docker Python module and have fun:
https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/